# How to Use Catch Block for General error

Tags: java, spring, ms-access, spring-mvc

I am doing a Project in which I have to validate a form on combination of First name and Last name.

Instead of writing my own logic, I have seen a Pattern in my Database that, if I am giving a Duplicate combination of First and Last Name then it is Giving a general error which is "`General error at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException`" in my Console.

I want to use that Logic itself, in my DAO layer I have, try catch block, I want to use that catch block to return an Object to my service and Controller, and accordingly I have to add an alert that bad combination or something like that.

Can anyone Help me on this ??

???

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Let's see the code.

Comment: You're connection URL might be wrong. Check your username & password.

Comment: @onepotato No you didnt get me actually, actually everything is running fine, but when i am inserting a Combination of duplicate first name and last name, then only it is giving that General Error... not in any other case, I just want to use that property of database, to generate an alert.on the jsp page itself that Bad Combination of first name and Last name.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:: My database is MS-Access and i am Using Jdbc-odbc driver...

Comment: What does your try {....} catch(Exception e) {} look like?  Are you catching just Exception? Code would be helpful.

Comment: @Tony::Added the code, Take a look , What i want to do is to print an alert on jsp page, instead of Console..

Comment: you might want to try just catching Exception to just see what your getting because it might not be an SQLException.  After you know what is going on then you can deal with it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your requirement that you want to send an alert to front end if save is failing..?

To achieve your desired functioning, You can modify your code as follows:

```
    public String saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    String result=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    try {
         pstmt = getDataComnConnection().prepareStatement(saveEmployeeQuery);
         pstmt.setString(1, employee.getFirstName());
         pstmt.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
         pstmt.setString(3, employee.getDisplayName());
         pstmt.setString(4,employee.getAltId());
         pstmt.setBoolean(5, employee.isActive());
         pstmt.setInt(6, employee.getDeptId());
         pstmt.setInt(7, employee.getTeamId());
         pstmt.setString(8, "abc");
         pstmt.setString(9, "def");
         pstmt.execute();
         pstmt.close();
         getDataComnConnection().close();
         result="Success";
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         result="Failure";
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

As per my suggestion you have to edit the method to return a **result** String value.
You can check for the value in service layer and send the alert to application layer if **failure** is found.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't change it to String, because there are a series of Events affected by it ...

And it's return type should be Employee type (as my TL told)....

No problem i'll figure it out ..

Comment: Then you can add a String result field to your Employee data object and can use it like employee.setOperationResult("Success/Failure") before returning.

Comment: :: Thanks for the help..

Actually what i did was to carry the exception to the controller and then at the controller i handled it...

But your opinion was also right we can catch it at the DAO layer itself and after that we can perform our Operation's accordingly at the Controller.

Comment: Yupp..!  That is the way to deal with exceptions in 3-tier application architecture.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea to write your biz in DAO layer, unless that's data restraint. I think check a combination string should be write in your UI or biz layer.

Answer (score -1):

I think You can use try and catch(Exception e) do not use sepecific exception like IOException. And put System.out.err(e.getMessage()) in catch